# Break in debugger on Err.Raise

Tags: vb.net, exception, visual-studio-debugging

Is is possible to get the Visual Studio 2010 debugger to break when vb.net code is throwing `Err.Raise` ?

(I have found that stopping on *all* `System.Exception` works, but then I stop on several other exceptions as well, since the .net runtime sometimes throws and catches exceptions itself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Breakpoints window and add a new breakpoint at `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ErrObject.Raise`.
This will break whenever the `Raise()` method is called.

Comment: Thinking outside the box.
I like it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the debugger break command:

```
Debugger.Break()
```